# Handling 3D Interaction and UI Controls in Augmented Reality

Tags: swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

I'm playing with this [Code example](https://github.com/DaoKeLegend/Handling-3D-Interaction-and-UI-Controls-in-Augmented-Reality).

And I'm having trouble finding where can I replace the existing 3d objects with my own 3d objects programmatically created?

I want to keep all the existing functionality in the code example but with my own objects!

> Creating of 3d object.

```
 self.geometry = SCNBox(width: width!/110, 
                       height: height!/110, 
                       length: 57 / 700, 
                chamferRadius: 0.008)

 self.geometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
 self.geometry.firstMaterial?.specular.contents = UIColor.white
 self.geometry.firstMaterial?.emission.contents = UIColor.blue
 boxnode = SCNNode(geometry: self.geometry)
 boxnode.position = position
 boxnode.rotation = rotation
```

[image]

Comment: Does it have, to be programmatically, I can see The `VirtualObjectLoader.swift` already Loads all the model objects within `Models.scnassets`. why not create a SceneKit (.scn) File then you can customize that virtual object through the inspectors.

Comment: Thank so much for looking it up! Yes, you're right. Basically, I want to show a Canvas with a picture on it. The picture will be from a database and the canvas Height and Width will be proportional to the image height and width.  I'm already doing it with SceneKit, I updated my question with an image.

Comment: And if I use a SceneKit (.scn) File, can I freely change the width and height of it? Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: anything you can do in code, you can do in GUI to objects in the sceneKit (.scn) File via the inspectors