# Convert currency formatter to double swift

Tags: ios, swift

For some reason, I can't convert the Price string to double. 
When I do it always returns nil.

```
       func calculateAirfare(checkedBags: Int, distance: Int, travelers: Int) {


        let bagsPrices = Double(checkedBags * 25)
        let mileCosts = Double(distance) * 0.10
        let price = (bagsPrices + mileCosts) * Double(travelers)

        /// Format price

        let currencyFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        currencyFormatter.numberStyle = .currency

        let priceString = currencyFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: price))

         print(priceString) -> "Optional("$750.00")"
        if let double = Double(priceString) {
            print(double) -> nil

        }
    }
```

Comment: Why `if let double = Double(priceString) {  print(double)  }`?  When `priceString` is likely to be `$0.00` - this won't convert to `Double`

Comment: @MadProgrammer I just updated my question

Comment: Explain how `$750.00` could be converted to `Double`

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/a/29783546/2303865

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The price is already double from the line

```
let price = (bagsPrices + mileCosts) * Double(travelers)
```

thus no need to convert it to double. 
The code below will return a string with a $ symbol

```
currencyFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: price))
```

To get a double from that string then you need to remove the $ symbol

which you can do using removeFirst()

```
priceString?.removeFirst()
```

After that, the string can be converted to Double. 
The complete code is:

```
func calculateAirfare(checkedBags: Int, distance: Int, travelers: Int) {


    let bagsPrices = Double(checkedBags * 25)
    let mileCosts = Double(distance) * 0.10
    let price = (bagsPrices + mileCosts) * Double(travelers)

    /// Format price

    let currencyFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    currencyFormatter.numberStyle = .currency

    var priceString = currencyFormatter.string(for: price)
    priceString?.removeFirst()
    print(priceString!)

    if let double = Double(priceString!) {
        print(double)
    }
}
```

Comment: No need to create a NSNumber object. You can use Formatter's method `string(for: Any)` in your case `currencyFormatter.string(for: price)`

Comment: Okay, but how do I put the money sign back?

Comment: @John you want a double or a string?

Comment: I want a double but with the money, is that possible?

Comment: That not possible, the $ symbol can only be used with strings. you can add the $ symbol to a double and create a string

Comment: Do all your calculations as double but if you want to add the $ symbol then it must be a string.

Comment: have you checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782982/how-to-input-currency-format-on-a-text-field-from-right-to-left-using-swift/29783546#29783546

Comment: @byaruhaf can you help me with this problem? I'm willing to pay for it! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59699361/handling-3d-interaction-and-ui-controls-in-augmented-reality

Comment: @John will take a look, no payment needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your same formatter to go back to a number like so:

```
let number = currencyFormatter.number(from: priceString)
```

and get the doubleValue like:

```
let numberDouble = number.doubleValue
```

Comment: Right. A double will never be able to have the dollar sign. Only the string will be able to. Where you have `currencyFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: price))` is what adds that dollar sign. So you display this to the user, and utilize either the number or `doubleValue` like shown above if you need to calculate things or send information to the server.